# Algorithm from 'hexagonal' number sets

Tags: matrices, elementary-number-theory

For any number $i$, I need to get a specific result $x$. I figured out the $x$ for the first few dozen $i$ visually. I've been at it for hours and have run into a lot of articles with titles I can barely comprehend, and someone shared [this link](https://oeis.org/) which led me to finding that I at least appear to be on the right track, but can't find precisely what I'm trying to do.

```
r = 1
i: 1, 2, 3, 4,  5,  6
x: 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1
a: 0, 0,-1,  

r = 2
i: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18
x: 0, 1, 2,  2,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -2, -2, -1 
a: 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -4

r = 3
i: 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36
x:  0,  1,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2, -1
a:  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -2, -3, -5, -7
```

Where $r = floor(sqrt(2 * ceil(i/6) + 1/2))$

Where $a = (i - (3 * (r ^ 2) - 3 * r + 1)) - x$ (basically, the difference between the zero-index for $i$ in a given set and the corresponding $x$)

I believe only the first half of the sets are relevant, as the second half of each set is just $x * -1$, so focusing on those.

The use case is a horizontal coordinate for arranging hexagons in a very specific way, in a grid, but radially arranged by $i$ rather than a typical 2 or 3 coordinate grid. This works if I enter all the values manually, but I'm trying to abstract this out to use it for any number $i$ programmatically.

I definitely see the patterns emerging here, but the brain simply isn't connecting the dots. Also I'm decades out of practice.

**Update**

After much more research and many attempts, I came across this graph which appears to accurately depict the values I've already obtained, but I still cannot figure out how to engineer this:

http://oeis.org/A307012/graph?png=1